# Hash MySQL database schema

Tags: mysql, checksum

I would like to make a hash / signature of MySQL database schema (without data), in order to have a checksum of it, to ensure it is not modified by others.

How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need table checksum as far as I understand your question:

```
checksum table `table`
```

so, just make a checksum of an empty table, I guess

Comment: how about the whole schema ( all tables )?

Comment: I doubt you can get a checksum of a whole database using one command. So, I'd go with collecting all checksums of all tables in a database, then concatenating it together and evaluating `md5` of this string.

Comment: okay, understand it can't be done in a simple way. However, the CHECKSUM TABLE query will also include data in the table to calculate the checksum. Is there any method to exclude the data?

Comment: Yes, it includes data. You need a copy of an empty table. What I'd do is `mysqldump -d database` - this will dump a whole database, then create test database, create all tables (they will be empty because of `-d` flag - `--no-data`) and do checksums. And yes, I don't think there is a simple way to do what you want.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the question. You wanted to check whether nobody altered tables. In this case I'd probably checked all tables with `show create table 'table'` and I'd have initial structures for all tables to compare. This is a bit simpler for me then making a dump and then checking all tables with `checksum`

Comment: I think my final approach is to dump the schema using `mysqldump` and do a file-based checksum, which allows me to make a single checksum for all table schema in one shot

Comment: Hmmm... i didn't think of it :) This approach is okay, but `mysqldump` includes information about it's version and version onf mysql server. If you upgrade/downgrade mysql server or mysql client (this will cause upgrade/downgrade of mysqldump), your resulting file's signature will, obviously, differ although schema is not changed. To avoid this, use `--compact` option of `mysqldump` like so: `mysqldump --compact -u root --password=root --host=127.0.0.1 test | md5sum`.

Comment: BTW, it was an interesting task for me too. `mysqldump` of a single database without data should be fast enough. I don't see any drawbacks. Nice question.

Comment: Nice idea. I tried it and got bitten because `mysqldump` outputs the auto increment values (which change when new rows are added obviously); but this [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15656501/1387519) gives a solution for that part. Thanks for the initial lead.

Comment: Sorry, but how this answer can be correct if `checksum table 'table'` for an **empty** table is always **0**, no matter what the table structure is? (MySQL 5.5)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT HEX( CRC32 ( SUM( CRC32( CONCAT(
   COALESCE(TABLE_NAME,''),
   COALESCE(COLUMN_NAME,''),
   COALESCE(ORDINAL_POSITION,''),
   COALESCE(COLUMN_DEFAULT,''),
   COALESCE(IS_NULLABLE,''),
   COALESCE(DATA_TYPE,''),
   COALESCE(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,''),
   COALESCE(CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH,''),
   COALESCE(NUMERIC_PRECISION,''),
   COALESCE(NUMERIC_SCALE,''),
   COALESCE(CHARACTER_SET_NAME,''),
   COALESCE(COLLATION_NAME,''),
   COALESCE(COLLATION_NAME,''),
   COALESCE(COLUMN_TYPE,''),
   COALESCE(COLUMN_KEY,'')
  ) ) ) ) ) AS 'hash'
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you explain your answer a bit?