# mysqldump - Export structure only without autoincrement

Tags: export, mysql, database-schema, auto-increment

I have a MySQL database and I am trying to find a way to export its structure only, without the auto increment values. `mysqldump --no-data` would almost do the job, but it keeps the auto_increment values. Is there any way to do it without using PHPMyAdmin (that I know it can do it)?

Comment: It looks like with MySQL 5.5 (server), `--no-data` will omit auto_increment values by default.

Comment: @JoeyAdams are you sure? That is not the behaviour I experience

Comment: @JoeyAdams MySQL 5.7.*'s mysqldump does not ommit the auto_increment when using --no-data.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can do this:

```Bash
mysqldump -u root -p -h <db-host> --opt <db-name> -d --single-transaction | sed 's/ AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]*\b//' > <filename>.sql
```

As mentioned by others, if you want `sed` to work properly, add the `g` (for **g**lobal replacement) parameter like this:

```Bash
mysqldump -u root -p -h <db-host> --opt <db-name> -d --single-transaction | sed 's/ AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]*\b//g' > <filename>.sql
```

(this only works if you have GUI Tools installed: `mysqldump --skip-auto-increment`)

## New UPDATE thanks to comments.

The `\b` is useless and sometimes will break the command. See this [SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283197/what-is-sed-b-command-in-linux) for explanations.
So the optimized answer would be:

```Bash
mysqldump -u root -p -h <db-host> --opt <db-name> -d --single-transaction | sed 's/ AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]*//g' > <filename>.sql
```

Comment: I don't think `--skip-auto-increment` is a real option. I can't find it in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html). Neither of the two MySQL bugs for this issue mention it: [20786](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20786), [30957](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30957). Which version of mysqldump has this option?

Comment: `--skip-auto-increment` is an option added in MySQL GUI Tools if a remember correctly. (not sure ^^) So in fact it's not really a solution!
But the second inline command is correct, I founded it [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20786) where the topic talking about **autoincrement** issue, and provide the idea of `sed` filtering!

Comment: Sed option would not remove all auto increments if you export multiple tables, only the last one. Also, --skip-auto-increment is not an existing option. How did this answer get to be rated so high?

Comment: you need a g at the end of your sed command: sed 's/.../.../g' to replace all occurrences.

Comment: This command is not correct. --skip-auto-increment doesn't exist. The regex is not correct. As p91paul noted the g modifier needs to be added in order to replace all occurrences. Use @JohnW solution instead.

Comment: The sed didn't work for me, I used `sed 's/ AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]* / /g'`

Comment: Would suggest removing all the attempts and just leaving the final one as new visitors arriving at this from Google won't need to know about the history.

Answer (score 55):

JoDev's answer worked perfectly for me with a small adjustment to the sed regular expression:

```
mysqldump -d -h localhost -u<user> -p<password> <databaseName> | sed 's/ AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]*//g' > databaseStructure.sql
```

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what that `\b` does within the sed statement, but as per @JohnW's suggestion here, the removal of that switch does the trick for me as well.

Answer (score 4):

It is --create-options, which is included with --opt, by default, which generates the AUTO_INCREMENT table definitions.

If you only want the base tables,

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uuser -ppass --skip-column-names --batch \
    -e "select table_name from tables where table_type = 'BASE TABLE' and table_schema = 'schemaname'" INFORMATION_SCHEMA \
| xargs mysqldump -hlocalhost -uuser -ppass \
    --no-data --skip-triggers --skip-opt --no-create-db \
    schemaname
```

If you want views, triggers and routines too,

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uuser -ppass \
    --skip-opt --events --routines --no-data \
    schemaname
```

Comment: Note that this also drops any auto increment fields, `drop table`s, character sets, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to this post, I was able to answer my question:

> How can I do version control on my db?

Then I just created this script: `db_bkp.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
filename="db_structure.sql"
backupfolder="/var/www/"
fpath="$backupfolder/$filename"
usr="DBUSER"
pass="DBPASS"
db="DBNAME"
mysqldump --user=$usr --password=$pass --no-data $db | sed 's/ AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]*//g' > "$fpath"
```

Then I added this to crontab:

```
30 5 * * * sh /home/scripts/db_bkp.sh
```

Then in my repo I added the result, `db_structure.sql` to git and before pushing changes to prod I always check if there's any structural changes I forgot to do on all dbs.

Answer (score -3):

mysqldump -u [USER] -p [PASSWORD] -d --skip-opt --single-transaction [DB_SCHEMA] > [FILE.ESTENSIONE]

Comment: This will also remove the auto_increment flag on the fields it's enabled on, not just the auto_increment value at the end.

Comment: `--skip-opt` discussed [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_opt) and [here.](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=22941)