# MysqlDump - no increment

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

is there any option to dump without auto_increment.
Keep the table structure with auto_increment 0

I use

```
mysqldump -u username -p dbname > db_dump.sql

CREATE TABLE `acesso_sistema` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip_acesso` varchar(15) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario_acesso` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `unidade` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `operadora` varchar(35) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `host_by_addr` varchar(35) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data_now` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=42 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best answered by reference to another question:

[mysqldump - Export structure only without autoincrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656463/mysqldump-export-structure-only-without-autoincrement)

Comment: If it's a dupe it should be tagged as such. If it isn't you should include the relevant information in your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm able to tag it as a duplicate. So I did what I thought was the next best thing.