# What is sed b command in Linux?

Tags: sed

I am just wondering what is the `b` command for `sed` in Linux.  For example:

```
sed "/some pattern/b" a.txt
```

Comment: See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Programming-Commands)

Answer (score 2):

The `b` command [stands for branching](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/unix-sed-tutorial-6-examples-for-sed-branching-operation/): unconditionally branch to label. The label may be omitted (as in your example), in which case the next cycle is started.

Note that in most cases, use of this command means that you are probably better off programming in some real programming language like awk, Perl or Python.

Comment: I find when the label is omitted it allows you to `think positive` about your data. By which I mean by positively bypassing lines it allows you to focus on those that remain. It can also obviate the need to group `{..}` commands.

Answer (score 1):

In POSIX [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) and GNU [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) — and other variants of `sed` — the `b` command jumps to a label in the script, or in the absence of a label name, to the end of the script.  It is an unconditional jump.  There's a conditional jump too; that's `t`.  And you make a label with `:label`.

In the context of the script in your question, the `b` is useless.  If the pattern matches, it goes to the end of the script, just as it does if there is no match.

For an example of when the `t` command is useful, consider the data file (`data`):

```
Be very, very, very, very, very, very scared of sed scripts with branches.
```

Now consider the outputs of these `sed` scripts:

```
$ sed 's/very, very/very/' data
Be very, very, very, very, very scared of sed scripts with branches.
$ sed 's/very, very/very/g' data
Be very, very, very scared of sed scripts with branches.
$ sed -e ':label' -e 's/very, very/very/g' -e 't label' data
Be very scared of sed scripts with branches.
$
```

Make sure you understand what the `s///g` modifier does and why the result is as it is.

I went poking around my `$HOME/bin` directory and found 97 scripts in it that use `sed`, including some very convoluted chunks of `sed`.  I only found one script (`rmemptysubdirs`) that uses `sed` labels and branching:

```
# Remove empty directories from paths

find "$@" -type d -print |
sed -ne 'p
:b
s%/[^/]*$%%
p
t b' |
sort -ur |
xargs rmdir 2>/dev/null
```

The `sed` script here converts a line containing:

```
/absolute/path/name/for/directory
```

into:

```
/absolute/path/name/for/directory
/absolute/path/name/for
/absolute/path/name
/absolute/path
/absolute
```

Note that the script uses a label `b`, not the `b` command.

Comment: Might want to note that GNU will branch to an empty label instead of the end of the script if `b` is used without a label name.

Comment: @123: I don't see the behaviour you claim documented in the GNU `sed` documentation on [branching](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Programming-Commands).